# How to add dynamic SQL delimiter of single quote?

Tags: t-sql, dynamic

I am developing a dynamic SQL using SQL Server 2008 T-sql code.  So I want to return values that look like "Jan'11".

My code looks something like:

`left(datename(month, SGD_SIGNOFF_DATE), 3) + ' + '''' +
' RIGHT(year(SGD_SIGNOFF_DATE), 2) AS MonthYear`

But this is not working.  Either I get output to look like "Jan11" or I get error messages.  What is proper syntax for my solution?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT LEFT(datename(month, SGD_SIGNOFF_DATE), 3) + '''' + RIGHT(year(SGD_SIGNOFF_DATE), 2) AS MonthYear
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

`left(datename(month, SGD_SIGNOFF_DATE), 3) + '''' + RIGHT(year(SGD_SIGNOFF_DATE), 2) AS MonthYear`

Answer (score 0):

I got it!  Here is the code now that works!

`left(datename(month, SGD_SIGNOFF_DATE), 3) + '''''''' +
 RIGHT(year(SGD_SIGNOFF_DATE), 2) AS MonthYear`

Comment: You don't need to post an answer with the correct answer. Just mark one of the answers above as correct by clicking the hollow check mark next to the answer. Please make sure you read the [FAQ] - this is site is a Q&A site not a forum.